# When to convert a local array to a malloc() in C?

Tags: c

Suppose this function runs indefinitely in a separate thread.
I need to change the local servers array size from 1024 bytes to 4096.

```
void * threadFunc(void * arg)
{
    char servers[ 1024 ];

    for (;;)
    {
       // Do stuff with servers, then sleep...
       sleep(2);
    }
}
```

However, it's unsettling to keep growing that array size since the default stack reservation size of the thread is generally 1MB. I'm considering these two options

**OPTION 1**

Update the array from 1024 to 4096

```
void * threadFunc(void * arg)
{
    char servers[ 4096 ];

    for (;;)
    {
       // Do stuff with servers, then sleep...
       sleep(2);
    }
}
```

**OPTION 2**

Replace the local array with malloc()

```
void * threadFunc(void * arg)
{
    char* servers;
    servers = (char*)malloc(4096);

    for (;;)
    {
       // Do stuff with servers, then sleep...
       sleep(2);
    }
}
```

I'm leaning towards **Option 1** because it's an easy change and the array should not grow much larger in the future.

Choosing **Option 2** is more complicated because it involves these scenarios:

1. The malloc might fail so abort the thread.
2. When to call free() to release the memory? Cannot call free() within the infinite loop as it's always needed. Cannot call free() after the loop because it's dead code which will never be reached. Also, if the thread crashes, maybe there's a memory leak?

**Question**

In general, when is a local stack array too large and should be replaced with malloc?

I assume **Option 1** makes the most sense for the specific function?

Comment: Option 3: define `char servers[4096];` outside the function?

Comment: How many threads?

Comment: Option 4: `static char servers[ 4096 ];`

Comment: How do you break out of your infinite loop when it's time to shutdown?

Comment: In general, when is it too large? When it exceeds the size established at link time.

Comment: 1) You should use a semaphore or "run" flag in the for / while loop so that you can exit the loop and join the thread. e.g. `while(run) { .. }`
2) Although malloc / realloc is OK to resize an array, this is often a poor practice from the perspective of memory locality. 
3) Although controversial, C does provide for variable length arrays since C99. You can choose to pass the array size as an argument to the thread function and then exit the function, join the thread, and restart to resize the array.

Comment: @WeatherVane static arrays are stored in the data segment. Therefore, they are shared by all threads. So, I'm hesitant to declare it as 'static' because in the future that function might be running in multiple separate threads. Nice idea! Thanks.

Comment: Yes, `static` variables are not thread-safe.

Comment: The only real reason not to do Option 1 is if your machine can't handle the combined stack size of all of the threads, and if that's the case, then Option 2 probably won't work either.

Comment: What is a "server" in this case? A character buffer? An array of...server characters?